# how to practise pronouncing r

Tags: pronunciation

I have been saying the 'r' sound using my top teeth and my bottom lips.

I want to start saying it using my tongue.

I *can*  do this, but find it tricky to work into words and normal speech.

How can I get better at using it?

Comment: My personal advice is very unfortunately, "get used to it". We ( Japanese ) don't distinguish between R and L either, so almost all people have an agony with this. But the different language is the different language....

Answer (score 1):

I recommend trying to "sound like a pirate": "ARRRRRRR!" Say "Ahhhhh" with your mouth wide open, then close your teeth. Then move your tongue up to the top of your mouth, ALMOST (but not) touching the palate, just behind your teeth (not touching your teeth) while still enunciating the "AHHHH" loudly.

Then do the same with words. Start with "CAHHHH" and shift it into "CARRRRRRR" as above.

Eventually, you'll get used to making the sound and can say it without being piratical.

Comment: The hardest part is definitely onset rs and not final rs